# store simple data in get_option()

Tags: database, options, customization

I am trying to store simple data, a few links inside wp_options. Basically using the following way: `update_option( 'simple_links', '<a href="">link 1</a>' );`

my question is if it is allowed, I dont want to create new table for it, just a few links permanently stored inside the footer. Is that the valid way and will it actually save data inside options? Or there is any other better way for such a simple need?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly valid way of storing some options in the database, however, it's good practice to prepend your option name with some unique characters pertaining to your site or something, like `'my_simple_links'` to avoid possible collisions. Also, if you're going to have multiple links you can store an array inside one option by passing the array as the second argument (serialization will be performed automatically). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Soulseekah Thank you so much! But how do I print the array then. I am trying that way but it just returns the word 'Array' no values: add_option( 'my_simple_links', $slink_array_new, '', 'yes' );

Comment: `foreach ($links as $link) echo $link;`

Comment: @Soulseekah what i meant is that then inside footer I call it like that <?php echo get_option('my_simple_links'); ?>

Comment: `<?php foreach (get_option('my_simple_links') as $link) echo $link; ?>`

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help, I've compiled an answer to your question, and if it suffices as an answer you can go ahead and accept it, or let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.array.php) `$array_var_name['value']` and objects: `$object_var_name->value`. Php.net is a good ressource for further research on that topic. Also: Don't forget to use `esc_attr()` on your values before dumping it into the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recap the comment chain above:

I think that's a perfectly valid way of storing some options in the database, however, it's good practice to prepend your option name with some unique characters pertaining to your site or something, like `'my_simple_links'` to avoid possible collisions with other plugins and themes that `add_option`s.

Also, if you're going to have multiple links they could be stored as an array inside one option by passing the array as the second argument (serialization will be performed automatically).

Accessing them from your theme would be as easy as:

```
<?php
    $my_simple_links = get_option( 'my_simple_links' );
    foreach ($my_simple_links  as $link )
        echo $link;
?>
```

Better yet store them in an associative array as `title => url` and do this:

```
<?php
    $my_simple_links = get_option( 'my_simple_links' );
    foreach ( $my_simple_links as $title => $url )
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>';
?>
```

And don't forget to read the Codex on:

- [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
- [`add_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)
- [`update_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Comment: You shouldn't use `get_option()` in the loop. Calling the function every time is a overhead. You should store the value in a variable first and then use that variable in the loop.

Comment: @Tareq it is not called in the loop. It is called once to form array to iterate.

Comment: @Rarst, although some PHP versions do go ahead and optimize this (my PHP version optimizes it to the point of calling the function twice only), I wouldn't depend on the implementation, and it has always been a best practice to keep evaluations out of loops.

Comment: @Soulseekah hm, really? From quick test function gets only called once for me (PHP 5.3.8) and I considered no-brainer that it would work this way. I do not argue separate variable is not worth doing, but I'd think policing this for overhead that isn't there is too much. :)

Comment: @Rarst, I agree with you, not much overhead, thanks for the edit to prettify the links, looks real good.

Comment: @Rarst is right, after some good testing and looking into http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, specifically "*Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself.*", so yes, it's safe to use `get_option` in the `foreach` loop without any fear of overhead.